# Doing stress testing on TCP server

Tags: node.js, stress-testing

We are using node.js(version 0.6.11) on CentOS(version 6.0) to build a TCP server. While I doing the stress testing, I found a problem:

The CPU usage of node.js deamon is only about 5~6% when less than 1150 connection established. But it rises to 100%
rapidly when only a few more connection established.

Does anyone know why it works like that? Is it a bug in node.js?

Here is the demo code:

```
var net = require("net");
var server = net.createServer(function(socket)
{
    socket.setEncoding("utf8");
    socket.on('close',
        function()
        {
            console.log('close');
        });
    socket.on('disconnect',
        function()
        {
            console.log('disconnect');
        });
    socket.on("data", function(data)
        {
//          console.log("recv");            
        });
});

server.listen(8080, "192.168.2.105");
console.log("Server on 8080");
```

Comment: How do you test this code exactly. Else I would advice you to post to github issue page.

Comment: I already did it.https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2987#issuecomment-4650835

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to Node.js 0.6.13. It could be a memory leak.

Comment: I made a silly mistake, I forgot to modify the number of open files.